# iOS app : lag issue when display a huge amount of small images

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview, uiimage

**Environment:**

I am creating a "[photo mosaic](https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=fr&safe=off&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1294&bih=738&q=photo+mosaic&oq=photo+mosaic&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i24l8.1141.1141.0.2483.1.1.0.0.0.0.52.52.1.1.0...0.0...1ac.2.0gxiTdE3WNE)" app, and I try to display 1024(32*32) pieces of small images(retina size->w:30px h:20px) on the screen same time. Which means on total, it is the same size as the full screen image size.

**Issue:**

I load 1024 UIImages, create 1024 UIImageViews, and add all of them to a UIView. When I scroll to this view, there is a big lag: test on iPhone4(iOS 5) and iPhone5(iOS 6). It's just appear on iPhone4, and on iPhone5 is fine. (Supposing iPhone5 have much more better CPU, so I think it is reasonable).

**What I think:**

Supposing all images have been already loaded from local dir in the memory(using method "imageNamed"), so I think the problem must be in the somewhere of the step display/render the images.

So any idea about it? Any, any idea will be helpful.

Thanks so much,

**UPDATE**

It is much better after I took the advice from @Antwan van Houdt . Here is the principle code:

```
-(void)updateCoverImageView:(UIImageView *)smallImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.coverImageView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    [smallImage.image drawInRect:smallImage.frame];
    self.coverImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Then you just set the alpha value of smallImage to zero, so the system won't render them. And the cover image will replace it. That works for the lag issue caused by displaying a large amount of UIView same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is every image in its own view?

In either case, for such a huge amount of images you should probably consider drawing them in 1 view and if that drawing method is still too slow you could draw it once, render the view to an image and then simply draw that image as it's cached display.

There are several guides available from apple that deal with the performance of custom view drawing and stuff like it.. you should give them a read.

Comment: Yes.. there are 1024 UIImages and 1024 UIImageViews been added in a UIView.. (I edited my post)

Comment: +1 for recommending custom drawing to prevent the use of unreasonable amount of UIViews.

Comment: @swang that is a lot of views... you know that every UIView has it's own drawing context? this isn't very 'handy' for the memory usage of the app.. you really should move to less views.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I agree with you. So I am tying to do some optimizations: Every image show with a little animation, once the animation finished, I draw the small image side by side in a single view. Instead of add 1024 image view side by side. I will be back and update the post if it work(or not) :)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the full details of your code, any thing like this, should be done on a background thread. I would read up on graphics contexts, grand central dispatch and then use both those concepts to create the resulting image in another thread and then get the resulting image and display it in the main thread.

Infact since you have many images which can all be processed in parallel, it can be done very fast using GCD.

If you can post the code, I can help you optimize it.

Comment: Note that you must make the UIKit calls on the main thread, so you are really only instantiating and loading from "disk" in the asynchronous thread.